# Clarify: Processor operates at 800 Mhz and 200Mhz DDR RAM

Tags: memory, arm, processor, cortex-a8

I have an evaluation kit which has an implementation of ARM Cortex-A8 core. The processor data sheet states that it has a

> ARM Cortex A8™ core, which operates at speeds as high as 800MHz and Up to 200MHz DDR2 RAM.

What can I expect from this system? Am I right to assume that the memory accesses will be a bottleneck because it operates at only 200MHz?

Need more info on how to interpret this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The processor works with an internal cache (actually, several) which it can access at "full speed". The cache is small (typically 8 to 32 kilobytes) and is filled by chunks ("cache lines") from the external RAM (a cache line will be a few dozen consecutive bytes). When the code needs some data which is not presently in the cache, the processor will have to fetch the line from main RAM; this is called a *cache miss*.

How fast the cache line can be obtained from main RAM is described by two parameters, called *latency* and *bandwidth*. Latency is the amount of time between the moment the processor issues the request, and the moment the first cache line byte is received. Typical latencies are about 30ns. At 800 MHz, 30ns mean 24 clock cycles. Bandwidth describes how many bytes per nanoseconds can be sent on the bus. "200 MHz DDR2" means that the bus clock will run at 200 MHz. DDR2 RAM can send two data elements per cycle (hence 400 millions of elements per second). Bandwidth then depends on how many wires there are between the CPU and the RAM: with a 64-bit bus, and 200 MHz DDR2 RAM, you could hope for 3.2 GBytes/s in ideal conditions. So that while the first byte takes quite some time to be obtained (latency is high with regards to what the CPU can do), the rest of the cache line is read quite quickly.

In the other direction: the CPU writes some data to its cache, and some circuitry will propagate the modification to main RAM at its leisure.

The description above is overly simplistic; caches and cache management are a complex area. Bottom-line is the following: if your code uses big data tables in memory and accesses them in a seemingly random way, then the application will be slow, because most of the time the processor will just wait for data from main memory. On the other hand, if your code can operate with little RAM, less than a few dozen kilobytes, then chances are that it will run most of the time with the innermost cache, and external RAM speed will be unimportant. Ability to make memory accesses in a way which operates well with the caches is called *locality of reference*.

See the [Wikipedia page on caches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) for an introduction and pointers on the matter of caches.

(Big precomputed tables were a common optimization trick during the 80s' because at that time processors were not faster than RAM, and one-cycle memory access was the rule. Which is why an 8 MHz Motorola 68000 CPU had no cache. But these days are long gone.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the memory may well be a bottleneck but you will be very unlikely to be running an application that does *nothing* but read and write to memory.

Inside the CPU, the memory bottleneck will not have an effect.